# Should I use Hazelcast to detect duplicate requests to a REST service

Tags: hazelcast

I have a simple usecase. I have a system where duplicate requests to a REST service (with dozens of instances) are not allowed. However, also difficult to prevent because of a complicated datastore configuration and downstream services.

So the only way I can prevent duplicate "transactions" is to have some centralized place where I write a unique hash of a request data. Each REST endpoint first checks if the hash of a new request already exists and only proceeds if no such hash exists.

For purposes of this question assume that it's not possible to do this with database constraints.

One solution is to create a table in the database where I store my request hashes and always write to this table before proceeding with the request. However, I want something lighter than that.

Another solution is to use something like Redis and write to redis my unique hashes before proceeding with the request. However, I don't want to spin up a Redis cluster and maintain it etc..

I was thinking of embedding Hazelcast in each of my app instances and write my unique hashes there. In theory, all instances will see the hash in the memory grid and will be able to detect duplicate requests. This solves my problem of having a lighter solution than a database and the other requirement of not having to maintain a Redis cluster.

Ok now for my question finally. Is it a good idea to use Hazelcast for this usecase? 
Will hazelcast be fast enough to detect duplicate requests that come in milliseconds or microseconds apart ?

If request 1 comes into instance 1 and request 2 comes into instance 2 microseconds apart. Instance 1 writes to hazelcast a hash of the request, instance 2 checks hazelcast for existence of the hash only millyseconds later will the hash have be detected? Is hazelcast going to propagate the data across the cluster in time? Does it even need to do that?

Thanks in advance, all ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast is definitely a good choice for this kind of usecase. Especially if you just use a `Map<String, Boolean>` and just test with `Map::containsKey` instead of retrieving the element and check for `null`. You should also put a TTL when putting the element, so you won't run out of memory. However, same as with Redis, we recommend to use Hazelcast with a standalone cluster for "bigger" datasets, as the lifecycle of cached elements normally interferes with the rest of the application and complicates GC optimization. Running Hazelcast embedded is a choice that should be taken only after serious considerations and tests of your application at runtime.

Comment: Makes sense. One other question, so there is a .NET implementation of the Hazelcast client. However, does that mean I can only join an existing Hazelcast cluster from .NET or can I actually embed hazelcast instance inside a .NET application (similar to java) ? Meaning, can I create a new cluster of only .NET embedded hazelcast instances?

Comment: No it is a client only, that said, the cluster is still Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Hazelcast distributed Map to detect duplicate requests to a REST service as whenever there is put operation in hazelcast map data will be available to all the other clustered instance.

From what I've read and seen in the tests, it doesn't actually replicate. It uses a data grid to distribute the primary data evenly across all the nodes rather than each node keeping a full copy of everything and replicating to sync the data. The great thing about this is that there is no data lag, which is inherent to any replication strategy.

There is a backup copy of each node's data stored on another node, and that obviously depends on replication, but the backup copy is only used when a node crashes.

See the below code which creates two hazelcast clustered instances and get the distributed map. One hazelcast instance putting the data into distibuted IMap and other instance is getting data from the IMap.

```
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;

public class TestHazelcastDataReplication {

    //Create 1st Instance
    public static final HazelcastInstance instanceOne = Hazelcast
            .newHazelcastInstance(new Config("distributedFisrtInstance"));
    //Create 2nd Instance
    public static final HazelcastInstance instanceTwo = Hazelcast
            .newHazelcastInstance(new Config("distributedSecondInstance"));
    //Insert in distributedMap using instance one 
    static IMap<Long, Long> distributedInsertMap = instanceOne.getMap("distributedMap");
    //Read from distributedMap using instance two
    static IMap<Long, Long> distributedGetMap = instanceTwo.getMap("distributedMap");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (long i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    //Inserting data in distributedMap using 1st instance
                    distributedInsertMap.put(i, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    //Reading data from distributedMap using 2nd instance
                    System.out.println(i + " : " + distributedGetMap.get(i));
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```